# AutoUpdate of AIR application

Tags: actionscript, flex4

I am learning Auto-update feature of AIR application. I created simple application which is not working. code is below:

### AutoUpdate.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                   creationComplete="checkForUpdate()" >
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import air.update.ApplicationUpdaterUI;
    import air.update.events.UpdateEvent;

    private var appUpdater:ApplicationUpdaterUI=new ApplicationUpdaterUI();

    private function checkForUpdate():void
    {
        setApplicationVersion(); 
        appUpdater.delay = 1;
        appUpdater.isDownloadProgressVisible = true;
        appUpdater.isDownloadUpdateVisible = true

        appUpdater.isInstallUpdateVisible = true;
        appUpdater.isFileUpdateVisible = true;

        appUpdater.updateURL = "http://localhost:8081/DynamicWeb/release/update.xml";           
        appUpdater.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false; 
        appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, onUpdate);
        appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, onError);
        appUpdater.initialize();
                   } 
    }

    // Find the current version for our Label below
    private function setApplicationVersion():void
    {
        var appXML:XML = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor;
        var ns:Namespace = appXML.namespace();
        lbl.text = "Current version is " + appXML.ns::version;
        //Common.helpDetails = appXML.ns::versionLabel;

    }

    private function onError(event:ErrorEvent):void
    {
        //Alert.show(event.toString());
    }

    private function onUpdate(event:UpdateEvent):void
    {
        appUpdater.checkNow(); // Go check for an update now         } 
    }

]]></fx:Script>


<s:HGroup x="89" y="124" width="413" height="34">
    <s:Label id="lbl" />
</s:HGroup>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

---

*Initially  in AutoUpdate-app.xml and update.xml file  version tag is set to 1.0.0

### * server side update.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<update xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/framework/update/description/1.0">
<version>1.0.0</version>
<url>http://localhost:8081/DynamicWeb/release/Update_air.air</url>
<description><![CDATA[
 Typically, this is used to summarize what's new in the release
 ]]></description>
</update>
```

---

- Now I have exported application and installed it. After that i  changed version  on both file AutoUpdate-app.mxml  and update.xml(server side)   to 2.0.0 . Now i exported the application and dumped it to server (in 'release' folder where update.xml is there.).
  Now when i launch the application , Update feature is not working. Its nothing happening.
  CheckNow() method is called but doing nothing. Please help me.

I am working on AIR 3.1
Its not giving any kind of error. Only Updation Window is not working.
Please tell me what i m doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) trace real version and from update.xml and be sure you did it correct. You must be sure you run old app with 1.0.0 version. BTW, you can use property `ApplicationUpdaterUI.currentVersion` instead of `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.applicationDescriptor`

2) You do not listen events after checkNow() calling. Listen all events, like in this article. In

http://thanksmister.com/2009/09/13/custom-air-updater-interface-using-applicationupdater/ (see *UpdateManager.as#initialize()*):

```
appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(StatusUpdateEvent.UPDATE_STATUS, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.BEFORE_INSTALL, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(StatusUpdateErrorEvent.UPDATE_ERROR, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.DOWNLOAD_START, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(DownloadErrorEvent.DOWNLOAD_ERROR, updaterEvent);
appUpdater.addEventListener(ErrorEvent.ERROR, updaterEvent);

private function updaterEvent(event : Event) : void {
    trace(event.type);
}
```

possible, you missed some thing...

Comment: When i listen these events,i m getting updateError(ErrorEvent.ERROR). But i dont know where exactly the fault is ? can anybody tell me how to find bug?

Comment: trace or debug in Flash Builder event.message

Answer (score 0):

in your server side update.xml you should replace the tag **version** with **versionNumber**.
This changed since AIR 2.5.